# Rewrite IP address to show URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain on my server stack.zachstarnes.com and it is currently pointing to a Digital Ocean droplet. When you type in the above address in a browser it ends up showing the IP address that its redirecting to and I would like it to show stack.zachstarnes.com.

I added a .htaccess file in the same directory as the index.php file that has:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^107\.170\.67\.157
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.stack.zachstarnes.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this does not work because it still shows the IP address. I also made sure I went into the .conf file and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride FileInfo` am I doing something wrong? Any help would be great!

here is the error log

```
[Tue Mar 04 02:39:08 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Mar 04 02:39:08 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/bin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 04 02:39:08 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 04 02:39:08 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 04 02:39:08 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 04 02:40:27 2014] [error] [client 24.126.213.31] File does not exist: /srv/http/favicon.ico
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:58 2014] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:59 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:59 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/bin/suexec)
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:59 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:59 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Mar 04 02:50:59 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

and here is the relevant code from the httpd.conf file

```
#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/srv/http">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache error log?

Comment: @OSborn where is that located

Comment: Generally `/var/log/apache2/`, look for error.log

Comment: Stop redirecting to your IP address then!

Comment: @Brad I want to be able to type the url and it go to the droplet but I dont want to show the IP address I want the subdomain to show.

Comment: @zachstarnes It's not what shows in the browser bar as much as it is that you are redirecting to your server's IP address.  This likely has to do with a messed up Apache config, or something broken in your application config where it doesn't know what host it is.  Narrow it down between the two, then post the relevant config or code.

Comment: @Brad the only thing that I changed in my Apache httpd.conf file is the `AllowOverride`

Comment: @zachstarnes If that's the case, then you should be able to put a static file in your doc root, and access it without getting redirected.  Try it.  If it works without redirecting  you, then the problem is your code, in which case we would need to see relevant code.  Really though if it is your code and you're using some off-the-shelf something, check the config and make sure the correct hostname is in there.

Comment: @Brad I posted the .conf code for the root of the server

Comment: @zachstarnes Try the test I suggested.

Comment: @Brad am I placing the file on the server of the IP address or the server of the subdomain?

Comment: @zachstarnes Put some file like `hello.txt` in `/srv/http`, and try to access it with your hostname and see if you get redirected.  Your last comment makes no sense to me... are you saying you've set up a vhost for your subdomain but didn't make it default?

Comment: @Brad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48912/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-brad)

Comment: So basically the default domain is not set to your domain, you have no virtual host on the config file for the domain in question and u don't want it to  show the IP? You need to make a virtualhost for the domain in question on the httpd.conf!